# Python+peewee: retrieve a field after Model.save() (and trigger execution in Sqlite database)

Tags: database, sqlite, python-3.x, peewee

1. In my application I work with Sqlite. In one of the tables inside database I've implemented a trigger (basically, after an insert event on the table TAB, it has to update a column named **codecolumn** which depends on the **ID** PK field)
2. In my code I create and object from a PeeweeModel previously setted

   ```
   objfromModel = Model(params....)
   ```
3. After the execution of line:

   ```
   objfromModel.save()
   ```

We hoped to get appart from the _id field generated -in fact **objfromModel.id** is retrieved from DB-, but also the **codecolumn** new field generated by the trigger execution on insert event. But **objfromModel.codecolumn** is **None**

Question: is there a trick to make on Peewee in order to recover this new field generated in database by trigger.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately SQLite does not support the concept of INSERT ... RETURNING. What you could do is a couple of things:

A. After creation simply re-fetch the codecolumn. e.g. self.codecolumn = MyModel.select(MyModel.codecolumn).where(MyModel.id == self.id).scalar(convert=True)  (the use of "scalar" says return just one value, the "convert=True" says convert the underyling database type to a Python type. This is really only necessary if the database type is a date or datetime

B. Create a post-insert trigger that calls a user-defined function. Register a handler for the user-defined function on your database instance, and have your callback receive the new codecolumn value and set it as a database attribute in the callback. Hopefully this makes sense?

C. Move the codecolumn trigger out of SQL and into Python, making it easier to know ahead-of-time what its value will be. This depends obviously on what that column contains.

Hope these ideas help.